# Phase 10 - Can you hit on the same turn as playing a phase?

Tags: phase-10

Reading the rules it states that you must have a phase before you can "hit" on other people's phases.

That said, do you have to have that phase at the start of your turn? Or can you play a phase, and then immediately hit the other player's phase?

The rules seem to make it seem like you can, but that would make playing your phase first the least advantageous, since all the players after you would get a chance to hit on your phases after they play their own (and you didn't get to hit anywhere because you were first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the rules in front of me but I have always played that you could play on other players right away.

I could see that argument in a 2 player game that going down second would have an advantage but if both players are playing that way it is more likely that your opponent will just go out when they put down their phase and therefore stopping you from playing your phase and sticking you with a lot of points.  I would argue it better to move on to the next phase and get a small amount of points then not to go down at all.